# Change toolchain in a subfolder with cmake

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, toolchain

I have a project that builds using the `arm-gcc` toolchain, but it contains a subfolder (with a different project, related to the main one) that needs to build with `gcc`.

Of course, if I directly use `add_subdirectory` nothing works (the error is actually that `boost testing` can't be found).

I have read some `cmake` forums and it seems that the recommended option is to use `ExternalProject_Add`. I have done it and it works.

Still, I would like to avoid using `ExternalProject`. Is there any way of, in a particular subdirectory, overwrite the current toolchain with a different one, but only affecting that particular subdirectory?

Comment: This feels like it might be an XY problem to me.  Why do you have a subfolder that needs to build with your system compiler?

Comment: You cannot mix different compilers in the same CMake project.